# How do i make this button take the input and use it

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making an encryption type of thing where the page takes the user's input and changes it to encrypt it.
I have the code to encrypt text, but I want to make it so that the button takes input from the user and uses that.

I have tried many times to incorporate my code into the button, but it just doesn't work.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Enigma Ui")
lbl = Label(window, text='''Welcome



''',font=("Comic Sans", 16))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
window.geometry('350x200')
def clicked():
    lbl.configure(text='''encrypted



''')
btn = Button(window, text="Encrypt", bg="light blue", command = clicked)
btn.grid(column=20, row=30)
txt =Entry(window,width=10)
txt.grid(column=14,row=30)
def clicked():
    res = "" + txt.get()
    lbl.configure(text= res)
window.mainloop()
```

I expect that when I click the button it will execute default python code.

Comment: You have two definitions of `clicked()`.  The one place you refer to this function is between the two definitions, so the first definition is the one that gets used; the second definition is pointless.

Comment: Yes thank you but I really need to know how to take user input use default python code to transform it then spin it out above the buttton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Enigma Ui")
lbl = Label(window, text='''Welcome



''',font=("Comic Sans", 16))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
window.geometry('350x200')
def clicked():
    res = "" + txt.get()
    if res == "a":
        lbl.configure(text= "8")

btn = Button(window, text="Encrypt", bg="light blue", command = clicked)
btn.grid(column=20, row=30)
txt =Entry(window,width=10)
txt.grid(column=14,row=30)


window.mainloop()
```